# Dropdown em purecss não funciona em menu

Tags: html, css, dropdown

Fui criar um exemplo de menu **dropdown com purecss**, de inicio deu certo, os submenus apareceram tudo certo, quando fui fazer o mesmo exemplo só que no formato responsivo *(onde usei esse exemplo [https://purecss.io/layouts/tucked-menu-vertical/] do proprio site)*. **Porém o drowpdown não mostra os submenus das li de clientes, produtos, ou vendas do meu projeto em tamanho desktop**, aparecem somente quando a tela tá é redimensionada no tamanho mobile, mas em dekstop não aparece.

Alguma solução?

Projeto - **Obs: Executando o projeto ele ira ser mostrado em formato mobile, de maneira correta, mas em dekstop não aparece os submenus**.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="A set of horizontal menus that switch to vertical
    and which hide at small window widths.">
    <title>Responsive Horizontal-to-Vertical Menu &ndash; Layout Examples &ndash; Pure</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-UQiGfs9ICog+LwheBSRCt1o5cbyKIHbwjWscjemyBMT9YCUMZffs6UqUTd0hObXD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    
    ga('create', 'UA-41480445-1', 'purecss.io');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
</head>
<body>





<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->

<style>
.custom-wrapper {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    height: 2.1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}

.custom-wrapper.open {
    height: 14em;
}

.custom-menu-3 {
    text-align: right;
}

.custom-toggle {
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}

.custom-toggle .bar {
    background-color: #777;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    right: 7px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.custom-toggle .bar:first-child {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
    transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.custom-toggle.x .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.custom-toggle.x .bar:first-child {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media (max-width: 47.999em) {

    .custom-menu-3 {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .custom-toggle {
        display: block;
    }

}
</style>
<div class="custom-wrapper pure-g" id="menu">
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <div class="pure-menu">
            <a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading custom-brand">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="custom-toggle" id="toggle"><s class="bar"></s><s class="bar"></s></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
            <ul class="pure-menu-list">
   <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">Clientes</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Listar</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Cadastrar</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Pesquisar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
  <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">Produtos</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Listar</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Cadastrar</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Pesquisar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
  <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">Vendas</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Realizar Venda </a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Listar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal custom-menu-3 custom-can-transform">
            <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Sair</a></li>
              
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
(function (window, document) {
var menu = document.getElementById('menu'),
    WINDOW_CHANGE_EVENT = ('onorientationchange' in window) ? 'orientationchange':'resize';

function toggleHorizontal() {
    [].forEach.call(
        document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll('.custom-can-transform'),
        function(el){
            el.classList.toggle('pure-menu-horizontal');
        }
    );
};

function toggleMenu() {
    // set timeout so that the panel has a chance to roll up
    // before the menu switches states
    if (menu.classList.contains('open')) {
        setTimeout(toggleHorizontal, 500);
    }
    else {
        toggleHorizontal();
    }
    menu.classList.toggle('open');
    document.getElementById('toggle').classList.toggle('x');
};

function closeMenu() {
    if (menu.classList.contains('open')) {
        toggleMenu();
    }
}

document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    toggleMenu();
    e.preventDefault();
});

window.addEventListener(WINDOW_CHANGE_EVENT, closeMenu);
})(this, this.document);

</script>

<style>
.main {
    padding: 2em;
    color: black;
}
</style>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de um bom detalhamento no codigo fonte, verifiquei que a formatação do css na class .custom-wrapper tava impedindo de mostra o dropdown do menu. Retirei a formatação e funcionou